How many bytes does Python BinaryIO.wirte() write every time?
When writing to the BinaryIO, we are doing some checking to see whether all the bytes are written to the IO. If not, then do the writing again until all the bytes are written. I wonder what determines how many bytes would be written in every call of BinaryIO.write()?

The docs cover this Binary I/O: The binary stream API is described in detail in the docs of BufferedIOBase. Which then has the section write(b, /) where this is explained.

Thank you @AdrianKlaver! I wonder how to determine whether the underlining stream is non-blocking mode or not. Thanks!

I'm pretty sure the only way of finding that out would be find documentation for the underlying stream or read source if it's available, or failing that you'd have to observe behavior.
